# C# Efficient de-duplication of single Datatable column's data

Tags: c#

I have a Datatable with some data, example as below, and need to de-duplicate any names in the names field by appending [1], [2] etc.

Current code below, works but is slow on large tables.
Any tips on the most efficient way of doing this in C# would be appreciated.

Current Table sample:

```html
- ID Name  X Y
- 1 John  45 66
- 2 Paul  44 66
- 3 George  88 102
- 4 John  33 90
- 5 John  53 37
- 6 Paul  97 65
- 7 Ringo  01 87
- 8 Ringo  76 65​
```

Required Table sample:

```html
- ID Name  X Y
- 1 John[1]  45 66
- 2 Paul[1]  44 66
- 3 George  88 102
- 4 John[2]  33 90
- 5 John[3]  53 37
- 6 Paul[2]  97 65
- 7 Ringo[1] 01 87
- 8 Ringo[2] 76 65​
```

Current code below:

```
foreach (DataRow aRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows) // run through all
   {
   string aName = aRow["Name"].ToString();                
   DataRow[] FoundRows = ds.Tables[0].Select("Name = '" + aName +"'"); // Find all rows with same name

    if (FoundRows.Length > 1) // As will always find itself
       {
          int i = 1;
          foreach (DataRow row in FoundRows)
            {
             row["Name"] = row["Name"].ToString() + "[" + i + "]";
              i++;
            }
        ds.Tables[0].AcceptChanges(); // Ensure the rows are updated before looping around.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does the "first" copy of each name have to be left un-suffixed, and do subsequent suffixes have to be sequential?

Comment: @AdrianWragg Look at required table sample, also his code works he just wants a faster solution

Comment: @EpicKip I am quite capable of looking at a table sample, thank you. And reading a question.

Comment: Perhaps consider doing it in a SQL query using a NameIndex table column and updates when duplicate names are entered

Comment: @AdrianWragg Don't ask questions you already have the answer to then, the only name that has no indexer is the name that appears once....

Comment: @EpicKip At no point does he state that the numbers have to be sequential. He also does not state explicitly that the first of each must be left unchanged. There may be easier solutions if these are not solid requirements.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Omfg "Required Table sample:" John[1] John[2] etc. BUT only George does not have an indexer because there are 0 copies. Also if you just READ it says his code works, this means the code's working does not have to be changed but just has to be faster. Also his code just finds groups of names that appear more than once and apply index's to all rows in that group.

Comment: @AdrianWragg Also you can see in the `Required Table Sample` that the first does not remain unchanged except if there is only 1 occurrence of the name...

Comment: I give up. Feel free to continue arguing with me instead of trying to help OP.

Comment: @AdrianWragg If you just read `Required Table Sample` instead of saying he does not specify it specifically. This question is one of the few that show required output and still you ask questions about the output. So you can say "instead of trying to help OP" but what you are doing isnt exactly helpful either. If you just would'v understood the question and was able to read we wouldn't have this discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
//test data
table.Columns.Add("Name");
table.Columns.Add("X", typeof(int));
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "john", 10 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "paul", 44 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "ringo", 312 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "george", 30 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "john", 100 });
table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "paul", 443 });

//converting DataTable to enumerable collection of rows and then grouping by name, 
//skipping groups with only one row(such as george or ringo)
var groupedData = table.AsEnumerable().GroupBy(row => row[0].ToString()).Where(g => g.Count() > 1);

//iterate through each group of <string, DataRow>
foreach (var group in groupedData)
{
    int counter = 1; //counter for "[x]" suffix
    //iterate through all rows under one name, eg. John
    foreach (var groupedItem in group)
    {
        //add [x] 
        groupedItem[0] = string.Format("{0} [{1}]", group.Key, counter);
        counter++;
    }
}
```

EDIT: simplified code and made it a bit more efficient, as suggested by AdrianWragg

Comment: I've not tried running this myself, but you may be able to make this slightly more efficient by changing `group` to `group.Where(grp => grp.Count() > 1)` in your second `foreach`, and dropping the inner `if`.

Comment: @AdrianWragg thanks for suggestion, I'll edit my code

Comment: Nino (& AdrianWragg) Many thanks this solution, worked perfectly and a way lot faster than my original . Regards John.

Answer (score 0):

Probably old good `for` loop updating the whole table in one pass will be the fastest approach:

```
var foundNames = new Dictionary<string, int>();
for (int rowInd = 0; rowInd < dataTable.Rows.Count; rowInd++)
{
    // If name is not yet found in foundNames, then store its row
    // index. Don't update the dataTable yet -- this is the only
    // occurrence so far.
    // The index is stored inverted to distinguish from count.
    //
    // If name is found in foundNames, retrieve the count.
    // If count is inverted (non-positive), then we've encountered
    // the name second time. In this case update the row with the
    // first occurrence and the current row too. Store the count of 2.
    //
    // If count is positive, then it's third or even later occurrence.
    // Update the current row only and store the incremented count.

    var name = dataTable.Rows[rowInd]["Name"].ToString();
    int count;
    if (!foundNames.TryGetValue(name, out count))
        foundNames.Add(name, -rowInd);
    else
    {
        if (count <= 0)
        {
            dataTable.Rows[-count]["Name"] = name + "[1]";
            count = 1;
        }
        count++;
        dataTable.Rows[rowInd]["Name"] = name + "[" + count + "]";
        foundNames[name] = count;
    }
}
```